# How do I pass an unevaluated expression as an an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, expression, supplier

In Java I can declare a `Supplier<Foo>` parameter, get the value using `s.get()`, and create the supplier using `() -> someExpression()`, so the expression is only evaluated if needed:

```
static void doSomething(Supplier<Foo> s) {
    if (gonnaNeedThatObject) {
        Foo foo = s.get();
        // do stuff with foo
    }
}

...

doSomething(() -> someExpression());
```

How can I accomplish this in C++? There seems to be a few different ways, but I can't quite figure out the syntax or the benefits and drawbacks of each way.

Comment: `doSomething([]{ return someExpression(); });` and `static void doSomething(std::function<Foo()> fn) { /*...*/ };`

Comment: Oh, and if you need the expression to be lazy and only evaluated once and cache the result so it can be retrieved multiple times, you can do `doSomething([lazy=std::optional<Foo>{}]() mutable { if (not lazy.has_value()) lazy = someExpression(); return *lazy; } });`

Comment: @Eljay If you put your comment as an answer, it'll can be rated and will be easier to find..

Comment: If you want it to be lazy and thread-safe, use a `static` local variable for the shared value. It can be in the lambda’s body, for example. I would advice against the `mutable` lambda, because it either (a) fails its “singleton promise” or (b) is not thread-safe. **(a):** `doSomething()` as declared above takes a `std::function` by _value_, so `lazy` will always get (re-)instantiated. **(b):** To avoid (a), `doSomething()` would have to take a non-`const` reference, which won’t bind to temporaries and will (correctly) require a shared `std::function` pointee, which is _not_ thread-safe.

Comment: I'd prefer a templated `doSomething` over using the heavy beast `std::function`...

Comment: @JohnBayko • I don't have the time right now for a proper answer.  Feel free to use my comment and run with it.  Andrej points are also interesting, the `static` has the behavior that will be shared across all instances (which may be desirable, or may be undesirable, depending on use-case scenario); and the templated approach can be an important performance optimization (... **profile profile profile**).